# How to skip lines in Python

Tags: python

I am having trouble with this problem on Computer Circles, I know that it is probably a very simple exercise but well, guess I have a lot to learn.

The problem arises when nothing is inputted in one of the inputs. The last input is a `"END"` so I wanted to create some way to skip the other inputs (think `goto`) in order to prevent an error.

I would appreciate any suggestions for optimization/structuring improvements.

Thank you in advance.

**Code:**

```
width = int(input())
second = input()
third = input()
fourth = input()
fifth = input()
sixth = input()


lenght_of_second = len(second)
lenght_of_third = len(third)
lenght_of_fourth = len(fourth) 
lenght_of_fifth = len(fifth)
lenght_of_sixth = len(sixth)


periods = width - lenght_of_second 

periods_on_side = periods // 2
reminder_periods = periods % 2
if second != "END":
   print("." * reminder_periods + "." * periods_on_side + second + periods_on_side * "." )






periods = width - lenght_of_third 

periods_on_side = periods // 2
reminder_periods = periods % 2
if third != "END":
   print("." * reminder_periods + "." * periods_on_side + third + periods_on_side * "." )




periods = width - lenght_of_fourth

periods_on_side = periods // 2
reminder_periods = periods % 2
if fourth != "END":
   print("." * reminder_periods + "." * periods_on_side + fourth + periods_on_side * "." )




periods = width - lenght_of_fifth 

periods_on_side = periods // 2
reminder_periods = periods % 2
if fifth != "END":
   print("." * reminder_periods + "." * periods_on_side + fifth + periods_on_side * "." )




periods = width - lenght_of_sixth

periods_on_side = periods // 2
reminder_periods = periods % 2
if sixth != "END":
   print("." * reminder_periods + "." * periods_on_side + sixth + periods_on_side * "." )
```

For this program, the first line of input is an integer width. Then, there are some lines of text; the line `"END"` indicates the end of the text.

For each line of text, you need to print out a centered version of it, by adding periods `..` to the left and right, so that the total length of each line of text is width. (All input lines will have length at most width.)

Centering means that the number of periods added to the left and added to the right should be equal if possible; if needed we allow one more period on the left than the right.

**For example, for input:**

```
13
Text
in
the
middle!
END
```

**the correct output would be**

```
.....Text....
......in.....
.....the.....           
...middle!...
```

Comment: Can you also add some code?

Comment: Please show us a [mcve] of your problem...

Comment: `"For example, for input"`.. your text got cut off, please complete the example input

Comment: Sorry for the slip ups.

Comment: @Volkman is this question still open?

Answer (score 0):

I may come a decade later but I will still provide you a simple answer to your question: **use loops**.

```
width = int(input("Introduce the width:"))
lines = []
lastline = input("Write a line of text: ")
while lastline != "END":
    lines.append(lastline)
    lastline = input("Write a line of text: ")
for i in lines:
    print(("{:.^%d}" % width).format(i))
```

This works as you expect in the question. I hope it helps someone :)